# Add nodes to a fixed backbone when drawing a networkx graph with graphviz, some of the larger nodes are ending up crammed together

Tags: graph, graphviz, networkx

I have created a graph using networkx. I am drawing the graph using graphviz, specifically with these lines of code:

```
pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G2, prog='neato', args='-Goverlap=prism')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 14))

nx.draw(G2, pos, node_size=sizes, alpha=1, nodelist=nodes, node_color=colors, with_labels=True, labels=labelDict, font_size=8)
```

The graph consists of a "backbone" of a few larger nodes, to which are attached a few hundred smaller nodes.

I have used `args='-Goverlap=prism'` (in the first line of code above) to space out the graph, but this has created a problem. It matters much more that the larger nodes be spaced out, but, because of how many small nodes there are, some of the larger nodes are ending up crammed together.

My thoughts on a solution are to generate a graph with only the larger nodes to ensure that they are properly spaced, then add the smaller nodes to this graph without changing the layout of the original nodes. I have done some research, and it seems to be somewhat tricky to add new nodes without changing old ones in graphviz. It is possible to "pin" nodes, but I am unsure of how to do this within networkx.

This is what the graph currently looks like:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts seem reasonable.  The following code generates a graph, assigns an initial position to nodes 1 and 2, then uses `nx.spring_layout` to assign positions to all of them.  I allow for node 2 to move, but node 1 stays fixed.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.path_graph(6)
originalpos = {1:(0,0), 2:(1,0)}
newpos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=originalpos, fixed=[1])
newpos
> {0: array([-0.39442754, -0.35733777]),
 1: array([ 0.,  0.]),
 2: array([ 0.44050048,  0.3734393 ]),
 3: array([ 0.8658906 ,  0.80306291]),
 4: array([ 1.21367619,  1.27878715]),
 5: array([ 1.45676553,  1.72154196])}
```

For your case you would get the positions for your backbone and then use those nodes as your fixed list.